# Motorola EMDK sdk, barcode2 QRCode scanning returns E_SCN_BUFFERTOOSMALL

Tags: compact-framework, barcode, motorola-emdk

I’m testing EMDK .Net SDK 2.5 on a ES400 device and have managed to get basic barcode scanning to work. When I try to scan QRCode’s, I allways get E_SCN_BUFFERTOOSMALL. The ScanData.Buffersize is 112 which probably is to small, but **where can I increase the buffersize**?

The QRCode decoder is enabled. If I try the same QRCode with the DataWedge on the device, everything works fine. I have checked help files, samples etc without any luck. 
Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround!!
By using **Symbol.Barcode2** assembly, instead of the **Symbol.Barcode2.DesingCF35** assembly, I am able to control the buffersize with the statement

```
MyScanner.Config.ScanDataSize = 256;
```

If you need more control, it looks as if you are better off looking at the “CS_Barcode2Sample” project as an inspiration instead of the “Barcode2ControlSample”.
Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the buffer length on the ReaderData object via its constructor.  Then you pass that instance to the Reader:

```
MyReader.Actions.Read(MyReaderData)
```

That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel` to initialize the `ReaderData` buffer length to the maximum size.

```
Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData MyReaderData = 
    new Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData (
        Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataTypes.Text,
        Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel);
```

Comment: Thanks James, I am using the latest EMDK and the **Symbol.barcode2** assembly. It looks as if I will have to downgrade to the **Symbol.barcode**, unless someone knows how to resolve my issue using the **Symbol.barcode2** assembly. Here is the advice from Motorola regarding barcode2:
*This class library replaces the Symbol.Barcode class library.  It is highly recommended that you begin using the Symbol.Barcode2 class library as soon as possible.*